# Joining files with cat confusion

Tags: cat

If I do the following commands:

```
$ cat picture.jpg > copy1.jpg
```

and

```
$ cat -v picture.jpg > copy2.jpg
```

`copy1.jpg` is a perfect copy of `picture.jpg`, but `copy2.jpg` is a lot bigger than `picture.jpg`.

I assume this is because `copy2.jpg` has had each of what cat thought were its line endings replaced by a `^M`, and each `^M` is bigger in size than a line ending. Is this correct?

If then do `cat copy2.jpg`, I find that there are no instances of `^M` in `copy2.jpg`.

What's going on here? And can cat be relied upon for joining files perfectly using `>`, if its output can be different from its input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not just `^M`.  *Every* byte with a non-printable character (whatever that means in your current locale) will be expanded to a multiple-byte printable equivalent under `cat -v`.

If you're using `cat` to join files, you need to avoid every option that modifies the output: `-b` and `-n` (number lines), `-E` (mark line endings with `$`), `-s` (suppress repeated empty lines), and `-v` and `-T` (display non-printable characters using printable characters).

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis sounds correct to me. I would use `cat` to join files, since that's its primary function. Just do so without the `-v` switch, or any switches for that matter.

Using `cat -v ..` on the file has essentially trashed it. Did you try and open it in an image viewer? I tried your method and that's exactly what happened to mine.

You can see the evidence of this using the `file` command too:

```
$ file copy*
copy1.png: PNG image data, 1440 x 847, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
copy2.png: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

`cat`'s info page sheds a bit more light on the subject:

```
'-v'
'--show-nonprinting'
     Display control characters except for LFD and TAB using '^'
     notation and precede characters that have the high bit set with
     'M-'.

On systems like MS-DOS that distinguish between text and binary
files, 'cat' normally reads and writes in binary mode.  However, 'cat'
reads in text mode if one of the options '-bensAE' is used or if 'cat'
is reading from standard input and standard input is a terminal.
Similarly, 'cat' writes in text mode if one of the options '-bensAE' is
used or if standard output is a terminal.
```

#### So where are the ^M's?

If you open your `copy2.jpg` file in say `vim` you'll see that it's littered with them, for example:

[image: ss#1]